# Where to save the user files on a web hosting?

Tags: storage, web-hosting

I created a web hosting in Hostgator and would like to save some users' files (such as photos and videos) got from my website.
Don't know where should I save those files in my web hosting. I know it is better to save them in other external web services (such as AWS). However, as my project is still small. I don't wanna make it too complicated at the moment.
Should I save the files in 'public_ftp' directory? or just create a random folder in the hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Create a random folder for now but move to external hosting as fast as you can. Also, you should know the Hostgator is an [EIG hosting](https://www.onlinetoolsexpert.com/full-list-of-eig-web-hosting-companies/) company, that are known for many negative effects.